# How to make a Parameter available to all Luigi Tasks?

Tags: python, luigi

In the [Luigi docs](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#configuration-classes), the use of a `luigi.Config` class is recommended for global configuration.

However, I am running into issues when using such a config class in order to pass a commandline argument to various Tasks in the pipeline.
Here's a lightweight example:

```
import datetime
import luigi


class HelloWorldTask(luigi.Task):

    def run(self):
        print("{task} says: Hello world on {date}!".format(task=self.__class__.__name__,
                                                           date=GlobalParams.date.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')))


class GlobalParams(luigi.Config):
    date = luigi.DateParameter(default=datetime.date.today())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(['HelloWorldTask', '--workers', '1', '--local-scheduler',
               '--GlobalParams-date', '2018-01-01'])
```

The class `GlobalParams` defines a `DateParameter` which I would like to later reference in the `run()` blocks of pipeline Tasks.  However, this fails with the error,
 `AttributeError: 'DateParameter' object has no attribute 'strftime'`.

In the debugger, I can see that a `DateParameter` object is passed to the `HelloWorldTask` Task, but any attempts to extract the expected `'2018-01-01'` value passed at runtime fails.

Am I misunderstanding how to use these constructs?  How should I be passing a single parameter to (possibly many) Tasks?

Comment: just access the default value this way: `GlobalParams.date._default.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')`

Comment: This only gives access to the default value as given in the parameter definition.  I want to access the date passed to the parameter at runtime (`'2018-01-01'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in the example code is that the GlobalParams class is not being instantiated before its parameter is accessed.
`GlobalParams.date.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')` should read `GlobalParams().date.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')`.

This is included, but easy to overlook, in the configuration docs linked in the question.

Comment: This doesn't work if I try to run with more than 1 workers, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Beware Windows people, it seems that Veltzer Doron recently opened a bug at Spotify, and the people there confirmed that **Global parameters are not propagated to parallel workers on Windows** (they are on Linux). See [Global parameters when workers != 1 not being passed to workers · Issue #2693 · spotify/luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2693).